Combine Balancer and Rewrite Engine in Apache2
I am running an Apache reverse proxy pointing to a web app running on 127.0.0.1:8080 with this config:
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket
    RewriteRule /(.*) ws://127.0.0.1:8080/$1 [P,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket
    RewriteRule /(.*) http://127.0.0.1:8080/$1 [P,L]

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/file.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/file.key
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    Redirect / https://my.domain.org/
</VirtualHost>

However, I want to use the Balancer to run two (or more) instances (e.g. one on port 8080 and one on port 8081). For simple apps that don't need the RewriteEngine, I can use this config:
<VirtualHost *:443>
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
    BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:8080
    BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:8081
</Proxy>

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/
    ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/file.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/file.key
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    Redirect / https://my.domain.org/
</VirtualHost>

Could someone help me combining these two configs?
I tried
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket
    RewriteRule /(.*) ws://127.0.0.1:8080/$1 [P,L]
    RewriteRule /(.*) ws://127.0.0.1:8081/$1 [P,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket
    RewriteRule /(.*) http://127.0.0.1:8080/$1 [P,L]
    RewriteRule /(.*) http://127.0.0.1:8081/$1 [P,L]

which of course didn't work, because this only addresses the 8081 app.
I also tried
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket
    RewriteRule /(.*) balancer://mycluster/$1 [P,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket
    RewriteRule /(.*) balancer://mycluster/$1 [P,L]

but this also didn't work. I guess because the first rule is pointing to http://127.0.0.1:8080 instead of ws://127.0.0.1:8080.
Any ideas? It's mostly based on this, this and this tutorial.
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::EDIT::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
I tried something based on this and at least it's not throwing any errors. However, when I place the two running localhosts stdout next to each other both are working in parallel with only me connected. Shouldn't only one be working at a time? Or can they split work even better then just one server handling a complete query and the second handling the other query?
What is this route=x part? Could I link http://127.0.0.1:8080 to ws://127.0.0.1:8080, if I set them to the same route?
<VirtualHost *:443>
<Proxy balancer://myclusterhttp>
    BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:8080
    BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:8081
</Proxy>

<Proxy balancer://myclusterws>
    BalancerMember ws://127.0.0.1:8080
    BalancerMember ws://127.0.0.1:8081
</Proxy>

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket
    RewriteRule /(.*) balancer://myclusterws/$1 [P,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket
    RewriteRule /(.*) balancer://myclusterhttp/$1 [P,L]

    ProxyPass / balancer://myclusterhttp/
    ProxyPassReverse / balancer://myclusterhttp/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/file.cert
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/file.key
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    Redirect / https://my.domain.org/
</VirtualHost>


Could you try something like this? I would separete the websockets from http traffic and then i should work like this in theory. Unfortunately i dont have a setup to test this out right now.
    <Proxy "balancer://mycluster">
        BalancerMember "http://127.0.0.1:8080"
        BalancerMember "http://127.0.0.1:8081"
        # Adjust `loadfactor` or `status` as needed for balancing (maybe thats the curicial part here balancing to the different hosts
    </Proxy>

    <Proxy "balancer://mycluster_ws">
        BalancerMember "ws://127.0.0.1:8080"
        BalancerMember "ws://127.0.0.1:8081"
    </Proxy>


    # WebSocket 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*) balancer://mycluster_ws/$1 [P,L]

    # Regular traffic
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*) balancer://mycluster/$1 [P,L]

    ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/
    ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster/


Sorry, I've just now seen your answer. I found a very similar solution that I'll add to my question. Was a little busy :). I'll check the differences in detail and maybe you could also comment on the other solution.

I think our solution are pretty much the same, instead of the ProxyPreserveHost On and RewriteEngine on parts. Could you maybe elaborate the role of route=X in the original answer?

And you also set [NC] behind the RewriteCond. Could you explain, what this does?
